# Choosing to make a function a member, non-member, private, public, etc

Tags: c++, member, non-member-functions

I've searched around for descriptions of the difference between member and non-member functions and, while I'm still quite confused, I thought I'd give an example to clear things up for me a bit. Here's a question from an old test our instructor gave us as study material:

Assume we have a main() program that uses the queue2.h and node2.h template implementations from our text, creating a queue of letters  (queue letters).

1. We want to write a stream operator to insert all characters of a string (thing) into a queue (letters << thing;).

(b) Should we make this << a member or non-member? 
Private, public, friend, or neither?

1. We want to provide a tool (call it Get_Front) which returns the head pointer of this queue of characters for future manipulations using the linked list tool kit.
   So, list_head_insert(head_ptr, '2') will place a ‘2’ at the front of my queue when everything is coded properly.

(b) Should we make Get_Front a member or non-member?
Private, public, friend, or neither?

I'm guessing the first one should be implemented as a non-member with a friend function, but I'm not sure on the specifics as to why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make the things that need to access private data members member functions and the things that don't (or don't *have* to be member functions) free functions. [This is a good read.](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(b) Should we make this << a member or non-member? Private, public, friend, or neither?

Member, public.
You create a queue object and overload insertion operator as member function. It can be used to insert characters into the queue.

Reason: We wanted to insert in queue stream and not in external stream such as cout.
It is better practice to use Member functions whenever you can. Friends should be used only when members can't be used.

Get_Front() becomes a public member function.

Comment: I agree that member functions should generally be used over friend functions, but not over non-friend free functions.

Comment: @chris: you mean C type functions ? could you please elaborate

Comment: I mean if a function doesn't need to access the private parts of your class, why give it the ability to do so?

Comment: @chris: Yes, in that case, we can use non-friend, non-member functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say not know the true purpose of the program which you have described above. I can give you somewhat of a general answer.

Make a function

1. PUBLIC if you want it to be accessed by anyone.
2. PRIVATE if you want only member functions and friends of that class to access.
3. PROTECTED if you want only member functions and friends of that class as well as member functions and friends of derived class to access.
4. FRIEND if you want to access the classes private members.

As far as member & non-member is concerned, again it is difficult to say without knowing 
details about the implementation. If the function has to access private members of the class, it would have to be a member function.